# Creating a rounded side of an element using pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, clip-path

I need to recreate this as an HTML element. It cannot be an SVG, and there must be text content inside. Preferably, it should be responsive as the element should also resize when the text inside breaks onto a new line.

[image]

I've already skewed the element a bit, the last piece of the puzzle is to create the rounded side on the right side.

I've tried playing around a bit using the `::after` pseudo-element, but I cannot seem to get remotely close.

Something like this is how I approached the issue (not including all my horrible attempts):

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  transform: matrix(1, -0.03, 0.03, 1, 0, 0);
  padding: 0px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Short text</p>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you manipulate border-radius like 
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 75%;

Answer (score 1):

One approach is, as follows, to use a CSS `radial-gradient()` as a `background-image`, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/* defining a shared CSS custom property: */
:root {
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

/* a simple means of ensuring common cross-browser sizing
   of elements, to include the width and padding within
   the declared sizes; also to remove browser default
   padding and margins: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 80%, 1200px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.container {
  /* defining custom properties for the .container elements,
     and any descendant elements: */
  /* the desired background-color */
  --backgroundColor: crimson;
  /* the distance between the center of the gradient and the
     point at which the color should begin: */
  --transparentRadius: 1rem;
  /* the horizontal radius of the ellipse */
  --rx: 0.5rem;
  /* the vertical radius of the ellipse: */
  --ry: 30%;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      /* specifying the ellipse (as opposed to 'circle'), with
         a horizontal diameter of two times the radius,
         similarly defining the vertical radius: */
      ellipse calc(2 * var(--rx)) calc(var(--ry) * 2)
        /* positioning the center of the gradient at the horizontal
           point of 100% - 50% of the radius, and vertically at
           50% of the element's size on the y-axis: */
        at calc(100% - (0.5 * var(--rx))) 50%,
        /* setting the start color of the radius (transparent, by default)
           which runs from 0 (the center) to a point --transparentRadius
           distance from the center: */
        transparent 0 var(--transparentRadius),
        /* setting the second color - the faux 'background-color' - of
           the element, starting at the --transparentRadius distance
           and continuing to fill the element: */
        var(--backgroundColor) var(--transparentRadius)
      );
  inline-size: 15rem;
  margin-block: 2rem;
  padding: var(--spacing);
  /* copied from your own code: */
  transform: matrix(1, -0.03, 0.03, 1, 0, 0);
}

.container p {
  /* setting a margin to the inline end of the <p> element,
     to ensure that the text of the element doesn't cross
     into the transparent area: */
  margin-inline-end: calc(var(--spacing) + var(--rx));
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container" style="--backgroundColor: lightpink">
    <p>Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <p>Short text</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v5Lgnw19/).

References:

- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Custom_Properties).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/radial-gradient).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

Bibliography:

- "*[Using CSS Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients)*," Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for the in-depth explanation of your approach. I tried playing a bit around with the CSS properties but I can't seem to get the desired output, I don't think an ellipse-figure has the right form to achieve what I want.

Comment: @Sigurd, thank you for your response; the ellipse approach was the best I could think of given the problem, but it is - honestly - all a bit convoluted. Best wishes on finding a better solution :)